# function triggered by multiple triggers google apps spript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

I have the same function which is called by several events (response to forms in the same sheet following a new entry on one of the forms), and I would like to know which sheet (the form) triggered the event.

I arrive well in the function, but I cannot find the argument which gives me the info of the source (sheet) of triggering

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have an installed trigger on form submit.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  let sheet = e.range.getSheet();
}
```

`sheet` will be the sheet object of the sheet that triggered the event.

Refercence

- [Event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)